# Unable to insert JSON Object into Firebase realtime database

Tags: android, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to store User data in my Firebase database. This is my code for handling onClick and sending the data to database:

```
public void onClickStore(final View view)
{
    String name = binding.getUser().name.get();
    String email = binding.getUser().email.get();

    DatabaseReference rootDb = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    DatabaseReference usersDatabase = rootDb.child("Users");

    Map<String, JSONObject> userMap= new HashMap<>();
    JSONObject userObject = new JSONObject();

    try
    {
        userObject.put("Name", name);
        userObject.put("Email", email);
    }
    catch (JSONException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    userMap.put("User_01", userObject);

    usersDatabase.setValue(userMap);

}
```

Unfortunately the app keeps crashing while trying to execute the last line of code (inserting map into the realtime database). Funnily enough, it works when I'm hardcoding the data to be inserted but not with either of `userMap` or `userObject`.

This is description of the error from Android Monitor:

> 03-19 08:20:34.937 22378-22378/com.example.jacek.simplyfootball
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                     Process: com.example.jacek.simplyfootball, PID: 22378
>                                                                                     com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: No properties to
>   serialize found on class org.json.JSONObject
>                                                                                         at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi$zza.(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                         at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zzi(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                         at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zzax(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                         at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zzax(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                         at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zzaw(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                         at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.zza(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                         at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.setValue(Unknown
>   Source)
>                                                                                         at
>   com.example.jacek.simplyfootball.RegisterActivity.onClickStore(RegisterActivity.java:89)
>                                                                                         at
>   com.example.jacek.simplyfootball.databinding.ActivityRegisterBinding$OnClickListenerImpl.onClick(ActivityRegisterBinding.java:290)
>                                                                                         at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
>                                                                                         at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
>                                                                                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
>                                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                         at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>                                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

Your help would be much, much appreciated. 
Thank you

Comment: Can you put the error message you get in the question?

Comment: I added logs to the question, I think it's to do with serializing my JSON Object, according to this line:
com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: No properties to serialize found on class org.json.JSONObject

Comment: Try avoiding JSON. Use POJO as recommended by [firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write). Like the one in answer by @Elsunhoty

Comment: You could also use the `userMap` without the `JSONObject`. That should also work. But you have to create a new key using `usersDatabase.push()` and set the map on the returned database reference. What you're trying to do, is creating your own ID named "User_01".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont understand what You wanne realy to do But..

instead of

```
JSONObject userObject = new JSONObject();
```

you can create model on user

```
public class Usermodel {

    String Name,Email;

    public Usermodel(String name, String email) {
        Name = name;
        Email = email;
    }

    public Usermodel() {
    }

    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        Name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return Email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        Email = email;
    }
}
```

and  create new object

```
Usermodel model = new Usermodel();
model.setname("");
model.setEmail("");
```

and go Ahead With Your code

Firebase will create it`s Primarykey if You want it

```
YourFirebaseRef.child("users").push().setValue(model);
```

Comment: as you can see I'm using data binding so my User class can't be done the way you wrote.. all I need to do is to insert my JSON Object `userObject` into Users node in my Firebase database which for some reason causes my app to crash