# FireBase Java error JSONObjects etc

Tags: java, android, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So this is my code:

```
public void sendButton(View v) {
    Message myMessage = new Message(username, getTimeAndDate(), getMessage(), chatroomName, Incognito);
    ref.child(myMessage.getChatRoomName()).setValue(myMessage.getJSONdata());

}
```

I get an error on the `ref.child(myMessage.getChat-etc` line and the error is:

```
Caused by: com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: No properties to serialize found on class org.json.JSONObject
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbtg$zza.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbtg.zzi(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbtg.zzaz(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbtg.zzay(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.zza(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.setValue(Unknown Source)
    at com.example.teo.myapplication.ChatActivity.sendButton(ChatActivity.java:63)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
```

Agh thanks! OH! and this is my JSON code "

```
public JSONObject getJSONdata() {
    JSONObject obj1 = new JSONObject();
    JSONObject obj2 = new JSONObject();

    try {
        obj1.put("Message", chatMessage);
        obj1.put("Username", username);
        obj1.put("isIncognito", Incognito);
        obj2.put(Long.toString(sendTime), obj1.toString());

    } catch(JSONException JE) {
        Log.e("Json Crash!!!", "Something went wrong here" );
    }
    return obj2;
}
```

You guys don't have to look into this error but I also got this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5254) 
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21174) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6862) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
```

And I don't know what it means as I'm sort of new to java (A couple weeks in ish)

Agh thanks!

Comment: Please Format code properly so that it's readable and easy to help

Comment: Firebase has no knowledge of `JSONObject`. Instead it relies on POJO/JavaBean conventions to determine what to serialize. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42885852/unable-to-insert-json-object-into-firebase-realtime-database